# not able to map domain name 53 to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am facing the issue with assigning the new domain name I brought in route 53. I followed the instructions in http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/setting-up-wordpress-on-amazon-ec2-in-5-minutes/ and get the wordpress blog running. But, I am not able to change the url to my domain name. I followed the above link, and changed to CNAME record, but still it does not work. can some one help me?

Comment: Does your DNS name resolve to an IP address? (eg if you ping it, or do a NSLOOKUP?) Can you provide more information about how you setup your CNAME? (eg does it point to an Elastic IP address, is the zone defined in Route 53?)

Comment: This is same as reported in http://serverfault.com/questions/664174/ec2-instance-not-working-with-amazon-route-53-domain-name.